Start correctly multiples gradle springboot postgresql project with docker compose at the same time
Context : I have postgres db on port 5432 with both of my services database called "bankAccount" and "contact" inside. My problem is that I don't know how to launch both "gradle project" at the same time with docker compose because it's either doing a timeout or an access database problem.
here is both of my docker compose:
contact (docker compose):
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://contact:5432/contact
    depends_on:
      - contact
    ports:
      - 8078:8081
    networks:
      - shared_network

  contact:
    image: 'postgres'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=msone
      - POSTGRES_DB=contact
      - PGDATA=/ContactMicroservice/src/main/resources/data
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/ContactMicroservice/src/main/resources/data
    ports:
      - 5433:5432
    networks:
      - shared_network

networks:
  shared_network:
    external: true

volumes:
  pgdata: {}

bankAccount(docker compose):
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://bankAccount:5432/bankAccount
    depends_on:
      - bankAccount
    ports:
      - 8079:8080
    networks:
      - shared_network

  bankAccount:
    image: 'postgres'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=msone
      - POSTGRES_DB=bankAccount
      - PGDATA=/BankAccountMicroservice/src/main/resources/data
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/BankAccountMicroservice/src/main/resources/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    networks:
      - shared_network

networks:
  shared_network:
    external: true

volumes:
  pgdata: {}

they have to be launched separately, but I have 2 major issues:
- 1  running on 8078:8081 is making a timeout ? I can't run both on X:8080 I tried it's not working
-2 running on 5432:5432 works but same problem both can't run on 5432 so I did 5433:5432 but I get this error with any postman request like that one : http://localhost:8080/contact/runs
2024-05-20T19:58:39.223+02:00 ERROR 22024 --- [start] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull com.run.start.enumeration.Operation] for value [Transfer]] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.run.start.enumeration.Operation.Transfer
        at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:293) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToEnumConverterFactory$StringToEnum.convert(StringToEnumConverterFactory.java:54) ~[spring-core-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToEnumConverterFactory$StringToEnum.convert(StringToEnumConverterFactory.java:39) ~[spring-core-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService$ConverterFactoryAdapter.convert(GenericConversionService.java:409) ~[spring-core-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:182) ~[spring-core-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]        
        at org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService.convert(ConversionService.java:92) ~[spring-core-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SimplePropertyRowMapper.mapRow(SimplePropertyRowMapper.java:141) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:94) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:61) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:733) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:723) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:754) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:767) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:825) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.DefaultJdbcClient$DefaultStatementSpec$IndexedParamMappedQuerySpec.list(DefaultJdbcClient.java:346) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.run.start.runner.JdbcClientRunRepository.findAll(JdbcClientRunRepository.java:23) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]    
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720) ~[spring-aop-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.run.start.runner.JdbcClientRunRepository$$SpringCGLIB$$0.findAll(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at com.run.start.runner.RunController.findAll(RunController.java:32) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]      
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:6.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:6.1.8-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]

If you have any idea what i'm doing wrong thank you for your time.
Tried to run 5432:5432 for one project it's working but can't run both on it so with 543X:5432 not working don't know the reason.
Tried to run X:8080 same here for one project yes but when i'm doing 2 it's not because 8080 get used by the other service.
